# Starting docker container with non root user fails

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, dockerfile

The following Dockerfile is based on an Alpine distro.

```
FROM minidocks/lftp 

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --update sudo

# Add user karate
RUN adduser -u 47001  -D karate
RUN echo "karate ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

The purpose is to be able to run a container using a non root user :

E.g.: `docker run -it --user karate <image_name:1.0> ash .`

But the aforementioned command wont do anything. It wont start the container and doesnt give any errors, although a container is run perfectly  for the root user (`docker run -it <image_name:1.0> ash .`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add following line at the end of your Dockerfile and rebuild, then you can run your command :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env"]
```

In the base image `minidocks/lftp`, following entry point is defined:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

So when you do :

```
docker run -it --user karate <image_name:1.0> ash .
```

You are asking `docker` to run :

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh ash
```

But the way how /docker-entrypoint.sh functions does not launch `ash`.

Whereas with my entry point, docker is running `/usr/bin/env ash`

Comment: correct. Can you share why is this working?